# not able to access data from hierarchy one to many relation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Project has many sites** and
**Each site has many remarks**

now in `project#show`, `remarks` attribute are not accessible by each `site`

here is my code -

show.html.erb

```
  <% @projects.sites.each do |site| %>
              <% site.remarks.each do |remark| %>
                <% if remark.status == false %>
                  <td class="rejected fi-x"><%= ' Rejected' %></td>
                <% elsif remark.status == true %>
                  <td class="approved fi-check"><%= " Approved" %></td>
<% end %>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
@projects = current_user.projects
```

remark.rb(model)

```
belongs_to :site
```

site.rb (model)

```
  has_many :remarks, dependent: :destroy
```

routes.rb

```
resources :sites do
 resources :remarks
end 
resources :projects
```

Comment: in rails console please check any site with remarks and show output . for example `Site.last.remarks`

Answer (score 0):

Your site model should include:

```
  has_many :remarks, dependent: :destroy
```

not

```
  has_many :sites, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Oh thanks it's typo in asking question it's already ```has_many :remarks``` but still not working code.

Comment: What happens when you call `site.remarks`? An error or an empty array?

Comment: nothing happens means no error is generated. but not able to access remark attributes- status, remark as shown in code.

Comment: Is your status stored as a boolean true/false or a string?

Comment: Go into rails console, find the site in question, and tell me the output of `site.remarks.first.status` please

Comment: error i am getting there as -```undefined local variable or method `site' for main:Object) ``` i am also updated route file.

Comment: @smith this error because site not local variable . please try `Site.last.remarks.first.status`